# Youtube Embed Iframe API

Tags: api, iframe, youtube, embed

I am having issues with the Youtube embed iframe api. Does anybody know how to not show the "Like", "Share" buttons and the player controls in the end of the video. I eventually used the following parameters:

`&autohide=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&modestbranding=0&hd=1&wmode=transparent`

I also added modestbranding option but it only hides the youtube logo while the video is playing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
<object width="640" height="360">
  <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/Zhawgd0REhA?modestbranding=1&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&version=3controls=0"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/Zhawgd0REhA?modestbranding=1&autohide=1controls=0&iv_load_policy=3&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object>
```